# europecv photo position

Tags: pdftex, europecv

Hi guys I found on the web a beautiful template to write my CV in Latex using `europecv` package. Unfortunately my personal photo using the string

```
\ecvpicture[width=12cm]{myphoto}
```

seems to appear in the center of the document while I need to put it on top right as reported for example here: 
http://www.tixus.de/blog/archives/2010/12/entry_1235.html

Can anyone help me please?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

```
\ecvbeforepicture{\raggedleft}}
```

Maybe you need an addition `\vspace*{-...}`